# Angular get specific field data from api

Tags: angular

I'm getting data from an API call with this code:

```
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res: any) => {
   this.myData = res['data'];
}
```

It's returning the data, but here I need a specific field "Name" in my component file. How can I get that single field from all the records.
I've tried this

```
this.myData  = res['data'].name;
```

and this
`this.myData = res.data[0].name;` (this return only the first one)

Comment: Dose `res` have a type?

Comment: No, type not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are collecting response names to your `myData` array, try this.

```
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res => {
   this.myData = res.data.map(obj => obj.name);
});
```

Comment: It worked!
One more thing if you could further assist, after getting these values, I need to set a status against every name which will show up in the Template (front end).
I have conditions if(name == 'abc') { this.currentStatus = 'xyz'; }
and that 'xyz' or any other matched value will need to display on front end.

Comment: then you should convert your `myData` array as ObjectArray and object structure should be `{name: 'server response name here', status: 'your status base on your name'}`. After that, access your myData ObjectArray in template as `myData[index].name` and `myData[index].status' etc.

By the way, please mark my answer if your original question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res.data.forEach(data => {
   console.log(data.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
res.data.forEach(({name}) => {
console.log(name);
});
```